# How to set option set values in Dynamics CRM Online API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamics-crm

I'm using the following ruby gem to connect to the MS Dynamics CRM API: https://github.com/TinderBox/dynamics_crm. I'm having trouble setting the value for any field that is an option set. Using the code below:

```
client.create('lead', firstname: firstName, lastname: lastName, description: description, emailaddress1: email, subject: topic, 
        companyname: company, telephone1: workPhone, telephone2: homePhone, mobilephone: mobilePhone, description: description, 
        parentcontactid: customer, customerid: customer, parentaccountid: parent, ownerid: team, campaignid: campaign, leadsourcecode: 4)
```

Everything works fine, except for the leadsourcecode. It returns an error saying `incorrect attribute type int`. I discovered that there is a virtual attribute called name for option sets, so I tried replaceing `leadsourcecode: 4` with `leadsourcecodename: "Partner"`, and it completed without an error, but the value was not set in the CRM. Does anyone have any idea why the value would not be set?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because are using the incorrect object type in the attribute. To set an option set in CRM you need to use an [OptionSetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.optionsetvalue.aspx) which takes an `int` in the constructor. Providing a straight `int` or `string` won't work.

Not sure about the Ruby equivalent, but in C# this would look like:

```
Entity e = new Entity("my_entity");
e["my_optionsetfield"] = new OptionSetValue(1);
```